# Read python list from a file

Tags: python, list

I printed a list `l` to a file using

```
f = open('a.txt', 'a')
f.write(str(l))
```

Now, How can I  retrieve the list from the file.

And the list `l` is a list of list of dictionaries.

Comment: why to retrieve it's already attached to the variable l

Comment: Use [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [`ast.parse_literal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Comment: I have to save the list for future purposes, to be used later

Comment: You can use [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

Comment: so you saved the list to text file and want to read it has a list

Comment: Feels like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array

Comment: @firelynx In that question, the OP wants to read the content of the file line by line in a list. I want to read the content in the original list format.

Comment: @ParagGangil didn't the first answer give you the result if so provide sample of the input file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not the best way to serialize data to a file, but to do the conversion back from string to list you could use `ast.literal_eval`.

e.g.

```
import ast

l = [['dir/path', 'other/path'],['path/path', 'blah/xyz']]
with open('a.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(str(l))

with open('a.txt') as fread:
    s = fread.read()
    l2 = ast.literal_eval(s)

print type(l2)
for i in l2:
    print i
```

There are plenty of better ways, pickle or json standout as good choices.

Note that as you append a complete list to your file each time, repeated runs of your code to write to the file will result in the file containing invalid python syntax that cannot be `eval`led back to a list.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to serialize into Json and write to file.

```
import json

ll = [ { 'akey1':'val1', 'akey2':'val2'}, {'bkey1':'bkey1', 'bkey2':'bkey2'}]

# write to file
with open('backup.json', 'w') as fout:     
    fout.write(json.dumps(ll))

# read from file
with open('backup.json', 'r') as fin: 
    ll_in = json.load(fin)

print ll_in
```

Comment: Overkill in what sense?

Comment: so how would you manage a "list of dictionaries" as the questioner asked?

Comment: see, if I would have read the question properly the first three times I read it, I would have never commented anything here. I'll delete my comments now kthnxbai

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way if to use Pickles

you can use it that way :

```
def createPickleFile(self):

    listToStore = self.traceManager.getData()
    fileObject = open("mypath", 'wb')
    pickle.dump(listToStore, fileObject)
    fileObject.close()

def getPickle(self):
    tesst = OrderedDict()

    fileObject = open(CONST_DEBUG_FILE_PATH, 'rb')
    pickleDict = pickle.load(fileObject)

    for item in pickleDict:
        print(item,pickleDict[item])
        self.traceManager.addValue(item,pickleDict[item])

    fileObject.close()
    return pickleDict
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ast:

```
import ast
f = open('a.txt').read()
l = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

The `l` will be a list object.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
f = open('yourfile.txt').read()
```

Comment: 'f' will a string object, how to parse it as a list object. Just doing l=str(f) won't work either.